# how to check wifi service on iPhone for uses wifi navigation in my app

Tags: ios, service, wifi

Can i check the state of wifi service. Is it enable or disable if user phone not connected to WiFi. I need it for create user alert, because i need WIFi state at "ON" state for my app with navigation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to import reachability classes in your project.

```
BOOL isConnectedProperly = ([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] == ReachableViaWiFi);
```

Ref:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: i use reachability in my app, but if user not connected to wifi, can i check state of wifi location service?

Comment: NotReachable,ReachableViaWiFi,ReachableViaWWAN there are this 3 status available

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Reachability Class for checking the network connection state


Reachability *internetReachable=[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];    
if(internetReachable.currentReachabilityStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    wifiAvailable=YES;
}
else
{
// Show the alert to turn on wifi
}
```

Comment: if user phone not connected to WIFI? see my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using the code apple provide https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
}
```